# center of mass coordinates formula?

Tags: calculus, physics

I am trying to learn particle scattering. In the textbook, it says that we can derive

d(V1,V2)/d(Vg,V) = 1

from Center of Mass Coordinate formula:

V1 = Vg + m1/(m1+m2) * V

V2 = Vg - m1/(m1+m2) * V

Vg := d(Rg)/dt := Rg

V := dR/dt := R

Rg := (m1R1 + m2R2) / m1+m2

R := R1-R2

R should be small r with an arrow on top but I don't know how to put it here

I don't understand how can we get the first equation equal to 1. Does anyone know what it means?

Thank in advance

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: Hi @ryan chandra, welcome to MSE. Could you please use MathJax to format your equations? Here is a helpful tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to understand the meaning of the different quantities without a picture. What are $V_g$, $V_1$ and $V_2$ ? When you write d(V1,V2), I think it's the distance between $v_1$ and $v_2$, but does dR/dt mean the time derivative of $\vec{r}$ or something? This notation is slightly confusing.

Comment: d means derivative, I cannot post pictures since I just joined. However, I just realized this is physics, not a mathematics topic so I will put this question in the right place. Thank you for the respond I really appreciate it

Comment: I think $\ $d(V1,V2)/d(Vg,V)$\ $is likely to be a Jacobian
$$
\frac{\partial(V_1,V_2)}{\partial(V_g,V)}\ ,
$$
but if $\ V_1,V_2,V_g\ $ and $\ V\ $ are scalar quantities with $\ V_1,V_2\ $ the functions of $\ V_g, V\ $ resulting from the equations given, then this Jacobian isn't equal to $1$, and from the OP' s comment it sounds like all these quantities are likely to be vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the complete set of equations in your book is the following:
\begin{align}
\vec{v}_1&=\frac{d\vec{r}_1}{dt}\\
\vec{v}_2&=\frac{d\vec{r}_2}{dt}\\
\vec{r}&=\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\\
\vec{v}&=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\\
\vec{r}_g&=\frac{m_1\vec{r}_1+m_2\vec{r}_2}{m_1+m_2}\\
\vec{v}_g&=\frac{d\vec{r}_g}{dt}\\
\end{align}
It would follow from these that
\begin{align}
\vec{v}_1&=\vec{v}_g+\frac{\color{red}{m_2}}{m_1+m_2}\vec{v}\\
&\left(\textit{ not }\ \vec{v}_g+\frac{\color{red}{m_1}}{m_1+m_2}\vec{v}\ \text{ as you have given it}\right)\\
\vec{v}_2&=\vec{v}_g-\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\vec{v}\ .
\end{align}
The quantity you want to evaluate is almost  certainly the Jacobian
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2)}{\partial(\vec{v}_g,\vec{v})}&=\det\pmatrix{\frac{\partial v_{11}}{\partial v_{g1}}&\frac{\partial v_{11}}{\partial v_{g2}}&\frac{\partial v_{11}}{\partial v_1}&\frac{\partial v_{11}}{\partial v_2}\\
\frac{\partial v_{12}}{\partial v_{g1}}&\frac{\partial v_{12}}{\partial v_{g2}}&\frac{\partial v_{12}}{\partial v_1}&\frac{\partial v_{12}}{\partial v_2}\\
\frac{\partial v_{21}}{\partial v_{g1}}&\frac{\partial v_{21}}{\partial v_{g2}}&\frac{\partial v_{21}}{\partial v_1}&\frac{\partial v_{21}}{\partial v_2}\\
\frac{\partial v_{22}}{\partial v_{g1}}&\frac{\partial v_{22}}{\partial v_{g2}}&\frac{\partial v_{22}}{\partial v_1}&\frac{\partial v_{22}}{\partial v_2}}\\
&=\det\pmatrix{1&0&\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}&0\\
0&1&0&\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\\
1&0&\frac{-m_1}{m_1+m_2}&0\\
0&1&0&\frac{-m_1}{m_1+m_2}}
\end{align}
If you subtract the first row of this determinant from its third, and its second from its fourth (which doesn't change its value), you get
$$
\det\pmatrix{1&0&\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}&0\\
0&1&0&\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1}\ .
$$
Then adding $\ \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\ $ times the third row to the first and $\ \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\ $ times the fourth row to the second (again, this will not change its value) you get
$$
\det\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1}=1\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry for the confusing question since this kind of things are very new to me so I am not get used to it